# can't view dynamically added elements from another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to retrieve all the inner elements of a table in Page1.aspx from Page2.aspx. I can retrieve hard coded 'table' elements whereas i don't see any dynamically added 'tr' elements (values). Below is my Page1.aspx.

```
$results.each(function(){
   $('#tbl').append($('<tr>')
            .append('<td>' + Item_val + '</td>')
            .append('<td>' + Name_val + '</td>')
            .append('<td>' + No_val + '</td>'))                                
    );
});

<div id="customerinfo">
<table id="tbl">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Item</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>No</th>                    
            </tr>        
        </thead>        
</table>
</div>
```

Now, I am trying to retrieve all the contents of the table in Page1.aspx from Page2.aspx.

```
load(function(){
                  $('Result').html();                    
               });


function load(callback)
        {
             $("#Result").load("/Page1.aspx #customerinfo", function (response, status, xhr){
                if ( status == "error" ) {
                  var msg = "error: ";
                  $( "#error" ).html( msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText );
                }
                if(callback){
                  callback();
                }
             });                                         
};
```

Comment: The javascript in Page1.aspx that creates the 'tr' does not fire when $("#Result").load(...) is run in Page2.aspx.

Comment: @Harsh: So is there other way around that i could load the dynamically created 'tr' elements or should i create 'tr' elements manually.

Comment: Instead using $("#Result").load, you can try loading Page2.aspx in a hidden iframe embedded in Page1.aspx. The javascript of Page2.aspx will run when it is loaded in this way. You can then get the HTML from the page.

Comment: @Hash: i haven't used hidden iframe, i looked a bit and i'm not sure if i would want to use it. Do you think triggering the function in page1 from page 2 would be a better solution?

Comment: I do not know of any way to trigger the javascript in page 1 from page 2 other than using the iframe.